# Building WPF app around third party control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have to convert a decent sized Winforms application into a WPF app following the MVVM pattern. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

1. The application is built around a third party map control.
2. Multiple windows: A main window that displays the map, and other windows that allow the user to change properties of the map (add layers, change styles, etc).

My plan was to create a viewmodel for each window, and have a base viewmodel containing the map control itself and any properties/methods that needed to be shared.

The main thing I'm not sure about is how to handle the map operations that are built into the control. For instance, there is a MapMouse_Down event. Normally I would just put this in the code behind if I wasn't following MVVM, and handle it there. Is that the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally I would just put this in the code behind if I wasn't following MVVM, and handle it there. Is that the correct way to handle this?

You could keep anything that is purely *view* related in the code-behind of the views but anything that is testable *application* logic should be implemented in view models. View-related stuff may for example be animations and any code that changes the behaviour or appearance of a control in some way, like for example setting some width or colour.

There are different ways to handle "events" in MVVM depending on what kind of controls you are using but you would generally defined commands in the view model and invoked these from the view. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) for more information.

Comment: Looks like triggers might be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Having a separate view model for each different type of window is ideal.
2. View models should never contain controls. They should contain only abstractions of the controls. If all of your windows have mapping components, only then should your base window view model have an abstraction of the mapping control. (An example of the sort of abstraction I'm talking about: Imagine a view that where the user should enter a name. The view will have a `TextBox` which has a `Text` property. The view model will have a `Name` property. The view will bind the `TextBox`'s `Text` property to the view model's `Name` property. Figuring out the right abstractions for larger applications is one of the challenges of MVVM.)
3. It's perfectly fine to have event handlers in your view if your controls don't support data binding or they don't have `ICommand` support. But the event handler in your view should do as little as possible, instead just transferring control over to your view model, which will update its abstract representation of the view, which the view will then re-synchronize to through data bindings or manual synchronization logic.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Right now I have the single map control in my mainwindow's view model. The view's ContentControl is bound to that map control. So that's not ideal? It sounds like all the control related functions will be in the code-behind, and have to talk to the viewmodels and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea exactly. In order to find the line between the view and view-model, ask yourself this question: If you ever have to switch your WPF front-end to WinForms or HTML or PresentationSystemXYZ (or if you ever need to target multiple presentation systems), would you have to change the view-model? If the answer is yes, you've violated the view/view-model boundary.

Comment: Another way to look at it: Your application has a map, and you have chosen to use a particular mapping control. There are other map controls, however. And there may be reasons why you would want to switch them later. If you have to change your view-model to do so, you have violated the view/view-model boundary. The view-model implements the core concepts of your application, and the view just presents those concepts. A well-defined view-model accurately implements and exposes the core concepts, and any view should be any to synchronize itself with that view-model.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is different for Winforms, the approach is based on the binding of proprety .
Below an Example of using MVVM.
[Easy MVVM Example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f)

Comment: Winforms has binding too. You can implement MVVM (or practically any design pattern) in Winforms.